# Does tidyr complete() use the dplyr group_by() function?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Does tidyr `complete()` use the dplyr `group_by()` function? I'm asking because I want to know if I need to `ungroup()` after using the `complete()` function.

I couldn't find an answer in the [tidyr reference page](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html).

Comment: I don't think so ... https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/master/R/complete.R

Comment: Agree with above, also if you print the object you'll see if it's grouped or not. You can also use `is_grouped_df()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the reference page you link states:

> Turns implicit missing values into explicit missing values. This is a wrapper around `expand()`, `dplyr::left_join()` and `replace_na()` that's useful for completing missing combinations of data.

So the three operations that are used do not include `group_by()` and indeed from a logical standpoint there is no need for a grouping-operation in `complete()`.

Finally as @Matt states:

> You can also use `is_grouped_df()`

This will simply confirm that the dataframe is not grouped.